# Why I don't see with docker search what I docker push?

Tags: docker, search, dockerhub

I'm logged-in as `georstoy` at [hub.docker.com](http://hub.docker.com).

`docker search georstoy` show 2 repos

```
NAME                      DESCRIPTION         STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
georstoy/firstcontainer                       0                                       
georstoy/cheers2019                           0
```

When I push a local repo like
`docker push georstoy/nginx` I get output

```
e2a556e0495e: Layer already exists 
03901b4a2ea8: Layer already exists 
latest: digest: sha256:b5e6442e5931a9c7b4dd5c7733c4b5803cd1878598499608dd4ca6e3e9c5ffe8 size: 739
```

I can see the new repo added at hub.docker.com.

But when I run `docker search georstoy` again I get the same result as before the upload

```
NAME                      DESCRIPTION         STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
georstoy/firstcontainer                       0                                       
georstoy/cheers2019                           0
```

I expected to see the newly uploaded repo in the search results.

Please explain this behavior of `docker search`!

Comment: Your questions not seem clear but Try to add different tag to your docker image

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you see local image in:

```
docker images
```

And tag your image before pushing it

```
docker tag <existing-image> <hub-user>/<repo-name>[:<tag>]
```

For example:

```
docker tag nginx:latest georstoy/nginx:latest
```

And then push

From docks:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/